# any ipv6 idea, how to get the RTP streams with the ipv6. vlan apparently doesnot support 

Tags: ipv6, rtp

Can you please help me with any ideas on generating the RTP streams with the ipv6 ?

I have tried with vlan , no success/

even i donot mind, getting raw dump of this stream, i just need to test ...

thankyou, Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe serverfault or superuser better forum to ask?  VLAN appears to be irrelevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your post doesn't make much sense, but I'll try to give you a helpful pointer regardless.

The VLC Media Player fully supports IPv6 RTP, and an example of doing an IPv6 multicast stream is as follows:

```
$ vlc some_file.mp3 --sout '#rtp{mux=ts,dst=ff02::1%eth0,port=1234}'
```

Hope that helps. :-)